# EWS Autodiscover endpoints

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I need to get value for X-AnchorMailbox and X-PublicFolderMailbox header for public folder requests. I was using both of those articles [first](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-exchange-docs/blob/main/docs/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-content-requests.md) and [second](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-hierarchy-requests) to retrieve values for headers but a problem happened during autodiscover process.

To send autodiscover request I use [derived endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-generate-a-list-of-autodiscover-endpoints) because i write my application in C++ and use only SOAP/POX requests to retrieve any data from EWS. If i understood correctly this kind of endpoints should be derived from user's e-mail address. So if the user has address user@test.onmicrosoft.com one of the endpoints should be https://test.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml (for POX). But this endpoint doesn`t work at all.

Is there any way to get correct endpoint or other ways to retrieve values for headers?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple endpoints (https and http redirect). Plus the endpoints from AD and DNS.

Start at [Autodiscover for Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/autodiscover-for-exchange)

In your particular case (redirect to a hosted M365 mailbox), you will most likely end up going through the unsecured (http://autodiscover.YourDomain.demo/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml) redirect (301, 302, 307, 308) to https://outlook.office365.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

You can also see autodiscover steps if you try the connectivity analyzer at
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/Ola/input

Comment: Thanks, this endpoint works great for SOAP requests. But there is a problem for POX: what does error 601 (Provider is not available) mean?

Comment: Nevermind. There was a typo in request body that haven`t cause InvalidRequest. Now I have problem The email address can't be found.